# Storing value of a text input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have an input:

In the controller I want to obtain the value of the text input by setting available. For example:
vm.inputValue = document.getElementById('link').value;

It breaks my code as I get a console error of:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add html code of the targeted element

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forget to set the id (`id = "link"`)of the input field in HTML:

```
<input id = "link" type = "text">
```

Also, you can do the same thing using `ng-model`

```
<input ng-model = "vm.inputValue" type = "text">
```

And from controller, you can get the correct value if you define a scope variable:

```
$scope.vm = {};
$scope.vm.inputValue = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS have a directive that does it to you, the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). It binds in a variable the input you enter in the HTML and it reflect the changes you make in the variable inside your controller in JavaScript.

In your HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.myText">
{{ vm.myText }} <!-- This is output the value of vm.myText in the HTML -->
<button ng-click="vm.logData()"></button>
```

In your JavaScript

```
function MyController(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.myText = '';

  vm.logData = logData;

  function logData(){
    console.log('Your data is ', vm.myText); 
    // This easy, you can access your value in the JavaScript
  }
}
```